# Replace text in Firefox, Pages, Terminal, BBEdit

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

I have a MacBook Pro running the latest Sierra.

I often find myself wanting to type `I²C` and have created `System Preferences/Keyboard/Text` to replace `I2C`. I can't seem to get this to work in any program (Firefox, Pages, Terminal, BBEdit).

The inbuilt omw doesn't seem to work either.

Is there any trick I am missing? I have set "Correct spelling automatically" and selected "Check my spelling as I type", which works for normal spelling errors.

Comment: There are many third party text replacement apps for mac. I use [aText](https://www.trankynam.com/atext/). I like that you can define where the I-beam pointer ends up, after the text has been expanded ...and that you can use it to trigger applescript as well. When I looked into these when I bought aText, it seemed like a good amount of functionality with low price.

Answer (score 1):

The specific parameter is Substitutions > Text Replacement, which isn't actually in System prefs at all.

It's usually in the View menu of individual apps & as far as I'm aware needs to be specifically enabled wherever it appears.

Apps that don't have that menu item won't do replacement. BBEdit is one of those. Most Apple apps have it, but not Terminal.

Comment: Thanks. I found `text substitution` in Page; nothing in Firefox (which is where I want it most). This leaves the question what does `System Preferences/Keyboard/Text` actually do then?

Comment: Correct spelling mistakes - & that's not global either, even though it looks like it is, nor will it work in any app that doesn't support Text Replacement, as far as I'm aware. I can see the reasoning behind it for 'code' apps, if you need to be talking about the fstab & it keeps correcting it to stab [real-world experience til I put it in my spellings] then it can get pretty irritating.